# Linux dpkg - where does it install to?

Tags: dpkg

I ran the following command successfully

```
dpkg -i library.deb
```

Where can I find where this file was installed?

Answer (score 28):

If you are asking where the deb package goes: `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

If you are asking where the files in the deb package get installed to, then do:

```
dpkg -L library
```

Comment: That's right. `dpkg -L` shows the list of files if the package is installed. To examinate it before install use `dpkg --contents library.deb`

Comment: dpkg -L takes the package name, not the deb file name.  So should be `dpkg -L library`

Comment: to get the package name run `dpkg --info library.deb` it will show next to "Package:"

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean with _If you are asking where the deb package goes: /var/cache/apt/archives_? - It is confuse because if you get the .deb file through the web into the Downloads directory, it stays there.

Comment: Correct about `dpkg --info library.deb` - it can be declared as `dpkg -I library.deb` too

Answer (score 13):

```
dpkg -L <package name>
```

(Although, since this isn't a programming related question, it should go on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) or [linux.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead of here.)

Answer (score 2):

Some of the answers have clarified to use `dpkg -L library`. It is not clear what to specify for "`dpkg -L`"; package name or deb file name.

Let me consolidate the answer.

1. Find out the package name from the .deb file

   `dpkg --info library.deb`
2. Use the package name found above

   `dpkg -L <package name>`

Comment: If you think other answers should be improved, edit them.